# calculate neighbors with NetworkX (error: The node 0 is not in the graph.)

Tags: python, networkx

I have a sample dataframe with a column for 'to', a column for 'from' and several columns for features relating to either the 'to' or 'from' colum.

I used `G = nx.from_pandas_edgelist(df, source='to', target='from',edge_attr=True)` to convert the dataframe to a NetworkX graph. I used `edge_attr=True` because I would like to keep the features for future analysis.

I want to calculate the number of neighbours for each point, so I used `neighbours = nx.all_neighbors(G,0)` however, I get the error 'The node 0 is not in the graph.'

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

```
import pandas as pd
import networkx as nx

df = pd.DataFrame({'to':[78,18,94,55,68,57,78,8],
                   'from':[18,78,35,14,57,68,57,17],
                   'to_Attribute_1':[18,78,35,14,57,68,57,17],
                   'to_Attribute_2':[18,78,35,14,57,68,57,17],
                   'from_Attribute_1':[18,78,35,14,57,68,57,17],
                   'from_Attribute_2':[18,78,35,14,57,68,57,17],
                  })
G = nx.from_pandas_edgelist(df, source='to', target='from',edge_attr=True)
[e for e in G.edges]

neighbours = nx.all_neighbors(G,0)
```

Comment: `nx.all_neighbors()` calls nodes by name, not by an indexed value.  Your graph doesn't have a node with the name `0` in it, which causes the error.  You could instead call `nx.all_neighbors(G, list(G.nodes)[0])` to get the neighbors of the first node.  @mozway's method is obviously preferred if you want the total number of neighbors for each node, though, since it loops through all of the nodes by name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should loop over the graph's nodes:

```
neighbours = {n: len(list(nx.all_neighbors(G, n))) for n in G.nodes}
```

Output (node -> number of neighbors):

```
{78: 2, 18: 1, 94: 1, 35: 1, 55: 1, 14: 1, 68: 1, 57: 2, 8: 1, 17: 1}
```